# Importing .TXT file into an SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, import, android-sqlite

I have currently a big amount of data that i have to populate into my application database.
Those datas are stored as formatted .txt files, and it would be suicidal to store them into my database by hand.
Here is what my .txt file look like :

```
ID_MODELE,MODELE,MARQUE,CATEGORIE,GENRE,CARROSSERIE,CARBURANT,BOITE <--FIELDS NAME
1,MITO 1.4,ALFA ROMEO,1,VP,BERLINE,ESSENCE,MANUELLE                 <--VALUES
2,MITO 1.4 MAIR,ALFA ROMEO,1,VP,BERLINE,ESSENCE,MANUELLE            <-- ...
```

The target database is an SQLite database !
If someone has a clue about how to perform something like this, i would be grateful !

Comment: You can write it's small parser which reads your input file line by line and makes "INSERT ..." statements to the table in the MySQL database.

Comment: I use an SQLite DB and not MySQL !

Comment: Sorry, my mistype. But, actually, it doesn't matter. I mean, I told you about the way you can accomplish this without any specific tools (except your favourite IDE).

Comment: Maybe check out this link:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial

Theres a nice tutorial about sqlite databases in android. It should help you solve your question by yourself.

Comment: My strong recommendation is: provide a prefilled database (you simply copy it from your assets folder to your database path and you're ready to go). It's a common practice.

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about SQLite, but databases like mysql have import functionality. The following is for mysql: Create the table with column names from text file, simply open the table view and you will find the import icon on the toolbar.

Comment: It's not an answer, is it? The question specifically asks about SQLite.